# Animation within an animation using AnimateAll add-on

Tags: animation

I already have an animation. It's really simple. A cylinder is moving a bit up, a bit down. But I want to also animate it in edit mode, using the AnimateAll add-on. When I try this and scale the cylinder's bottom face (and insert 'points' keyframes), the result is a scaled face throughout the whole animation. Is there a way around this? Thanks!

Comment: hello, maybe show some pictures, also, have you tried with shapekeys?

Comment: Hey. Thanks! It worked with shapekeys!